# Migrating Android questions

Tags: discussion, migration, android

Thank you for migrating questions about Android devices to [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com). I know they're off-topic here and we're happy to help folks at the site dedicated to the devices.

However...

*Please* be careful about what you send over. Questions about Android **DEVELOPMENT** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts. Android Development questions should be migrated to **Stack Overflow** instead.

Of course, the cardinal rule of migration is "**Don't Migrate Crap**".

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Al Everett

Comment: @ivo can you post an answer with some examples of good and bad migrations.. the diamond tools have a panel that shows you all incoming and outgoing migrations.

Comment: @Jeff, I couldn't find any bad examples, but posted an answer anyway

Comment: agreed, thanks for pointing that out @AlEverett, that is something we need to be more aware of...

Comment: @Al any reason to suspect we've been sending you guys (a lot of) crap lately?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/how-to-merge-video-files-with-ffmpeg-on-android http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/how-to-find-saved-wifi-password http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25511/can-i-sync-my-chrome-bookmarks-with-my-android-phone were all migrated within the last two days (and closed). There were a few that weren't so bad, but are so old the OP has certainly lost interest by now (and doesn't even have an AE account).

Comment: any reason for adding and then removing about bad migrations? Of the 8 questions that have been migrated in the past 8 days, all are still open.

Answer (score 9):

@Jeff and @Al

I've browsed through the last 5 pages of questions migrated from Super User, some of the questions we've migrated were closed, but this was mainly because they were dupes or crap.

None of them turned out to be migrated to Stack Overflow, unless the system shows those as migrated to Stack Overflow on Super User as well.

But still, we shouldn't dump our questions on other SE-sites if they're not of decent quality or simply off-topic

Comment: @JeffAtwood: : [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/250197/android-application-deployment-on-android-device?noredirect=1) was originally migrated to Android. I asked one of the SU mods on chat to migrate it to Stack Overflow instead. [I deleted it from Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/android-application-deployment-on-android-device).

Comment: @Al The link directs straight to SO, which makes me believe, which explains why I couldn't find them as migrated to Android.

Comment: It shouldn't. It has the "noredirect" URL parameter on it. At least, my link here does.

Comment: Ah no, I meant the first link :-) Not seeing that random had migrated it to SO, not you guys @Al.

Answer (score 4):

Incorrectly sent, re-migrated to Stack Overflow:

- [Android Application Deployment on Android Device](https://superuser.com/questions/250197/android-application-deployment-on-android-device)

More developer than end-user:

- [How to create customized Android System Images from the AOSP ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5176/how-to-create-customized-android-system-images-from-the-aosp)

Migrated, but closed as duplicate:

- [Android: how to get skype to work when the phone sleeps.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/android-how-to-get-skype-to-work-when-the-phone-sleeps)

Way old

- [Which is the Android's default browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/which-is-the-androids-default-browser)
- [How to delete the history and cache in Opera Mobile (10.1) via shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/how-to-delete-the-history-and-cache-in-opera-mobile-10-1-via-shell)
- [Install a web certificate on an Android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/install-a-web-certificate-on-an-android-device)