# Are questions about modifying Android hardware on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics, android

Questions about the Android platform on SuperUser are routinely [migrated](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2133/333963) to [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/), but apparently [questions about modifying Android hardware are off-topic there](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1787/65853).

So....**are questions about modifying the hardware of Android devices on-topic on this site?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally... I don't think so.

Practically when we deal with 'modifying' hardware on SU, its generic, and involving fitting in a component the hardware is designed to do.

If you are going to have to pick up a soldering iron to 'modify' a component, I do believe its far out of our scope.

Comment: Even if soldering etc. was allowed for PC components (which I generally see no problem with), we disallow questions about phones and electronic devices, so they're definitely off topic.